# slackTextViewController inside MXSegmentedPager not handling gestures right

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am using Slack Text View Controller https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController inside essentially a scroll view and its not liking it. I'm using this library https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager which handles vanilla collection and table view controllers fine but not the Slack one.

so slack is the child, and segmentedPager is the parent controller.

I have `textView.delegate = self` and set

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

method to true in both child and parent or one or the other to no avail. Not sure if this is an issue or if I am doing it wrong, any ideas? Specifically after scrolling down it wont scroll back up

Comment: can you give more details on what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure how to describe it, so here is a video clip: https://vimeo.com/155939607 as you can see from circles when i click to drag it pans down but not back up. The gestures are clearly fighting each other but i cant figure out where or why. Regular tableviews and collectionviews with stuff works fine in the mxsegmented pager

Comment: Still not sure what exactly was supposed to happen vs not happen, but generally what I do in these cases is throw them in container views. It's helped me with other navigation-type libraries

Comment: the scrolling is not smooth, and in particular it scrolls down but not back up. They're already in containerviews so to speak, the MXPager has the slack text vc inside it

Comment: have you resolve this? I'm trying to make this combo happen too

Comment: no unfortunately i abandoned this project